# Measure the total amount of data that is downloaded and uploaded in a given session?

Tags: linux, network-monitor, networking

I might have to use a monthly capped internet. So before I do that I want to find out the average amount of data I download and upload over the internet in any given day, such that the software starts recording when the OS boots up till the point it's shutdown. This way I will have an idea of need of my usage needs per-day and then from there on calculate for a month.

It would be nice if it does the monthly forecasts too but that's not a rigid requirement.

What software should I use to achieve the above on a Linux (Ubuntu 13.10)?

Comment: Another question I meant to ask: how do you connect to the Internet? If this uses PPP, there's a log message when you disconnect explicitly (I forget which log file it's in offhand). A caveat: if your computer crashes or shuts down without going through the software layer that shuts the connection down, no solution is going to reliably account for the latest bytes, but you can get a good enough figure by saving periodically.

Comment: It's a DSL connection (ADSL modem) which gets to me through another wire(less) router which has it's DHCP switched off so basically I'm using the modem's DHCP (don't know if it matters). Those crashes rarely happens in my case and plus I'm not expecting high accuracy just something that gives me rough estimate.

Answer (score 3):

While looking for such a software over the internet I found the article [How to Monitor Your Internet Usage So You Don't Exceed Your Data Cap](http://lifehacker.com/5821773/how-to-monitor-your-internet-usage-so-you-dont-exceed-your-data-cap). It suggested the use of [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/), which could be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install ntop
```

*ntop* currently start on start-up and automatically logs the network usage of every network device that is specified at the time of installation (*eth0*, *wlan0* etc) by date, month and year. Data usage can be monitored at `http://localhost:3000`. In short it does the job.

Lot's of feature won't be summarizing it here.

Comment: @BleedingFingers If you use this tool and find its solving your problem then you should accept this answer. Also please add your personal experience to this answer so future readers can conclude if they want to use it as well without having to visit the outside website.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Sure will after I've used it for a while.