# Measuring internet datausage?

Tags: windows

How can I measure my total internet data usage to avoid hitting datacaps by my provider? I have found [Measure the total amount of data that is downloaded and uploaded in a given session?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/measure-the-total-amount-of-data-that-is-downloaded-and-uploaded-in-a-given-sess), which asks for Linux.

[ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/traffic-analysis/ntop/) seems to do part of the job, but the problem is the stats are not saved when I shut down my PC, which means I have to manually export stats before shutting down. That obviously is a bit tedious.
And exporting would not really solve the problem because I would need to parse the json myself to get the data I want, because you can't import it again.

Comment: Did you research the other options leading from that post (notably: http://lifehacker.com/5821773/how-to-monitor-your-internet-usage-so-you-dont-exceed-your-data-cap)?

Comment: DD-Wrt is not an option as the router belongs to the povider,